# Nginx/PHP : Nginx is not returning a 304 response when sending Etag header

Tags: php, caching, header, nginx, etag

I'm trying the understand local cache with ETags and a nginx (1.2.1) server which redirects php's request to a php-cgi deamon.

Here my simple index.php :

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Etag:"5954c6-10f4-449d11713aac0"');

echo microtime(true);
```

After a second request, my browser send a If-None-Match header :

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:cache.loc
If-None-Match:"5954c6-10f4-449d11713aac0"
```

But my web server doesn't returns a 304 :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.2
Date: Thu, 12 Jul 2012 11:46:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.12
Cache-Control: public
Etag: "5954c6-10f4-449d11713aac0"
Cache-Control: public
```

Unless I've misunderstood, my server should compare Etag with the If-None-Match sent and returns a 304 response because they're the same.

Where am I wrong ?
Should I compare Etag with If-None-Match in my PHP script because nginx (or Apache) will not do the job itself ?

Regards,
Manu

Comment: Some PHP code, ETAG compatible https://gist.github.com/2313388

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you implement this yourself using php, *you* are responsible for also sending the 304 Not Modified.

So compare the If-None-Match header with your ETag, and use header() to send back the 304.

Comment: Or probably you can hack nginx as well to do that for you.

Comment: The problem is that nginx doesn't 'know' the current ETag, so nginx would still have to perform the actual PHP request first to find out what the ETag header was. This sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Sure, but nginx can then process the response headers before returning those to the client. Postprocessing.

Comment: @hakre
According to RFC it can't, because nginx isn't an original server.

Comment: @Evert FYI: AFAIK, that feature is included in nginx 1.7.3 onward, along with etag generation too.